# Web Tables in Selenium: Accessing child elements from parent elements with conditions

Tags: html, selenium

Hi I would like to find web table elements with Selenium, in which  has to have a specific class before searching for any  elements within the row with another specific class.

For instance:

```
<tr class="slots tr_mrng">
                        <td colspan="2" style="background: rgb(237, 237, 237); height: 0px; border: none !important;">
                            <table class="slot-table" width="100%" style="border: none; display: none;">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td id="15850908605e8209eda4133" class="reslabel" style="border:none !important;text-align:center;border-right:solid #36648B 1px !important" width="10%">
                                        07:01AM
                                    </td><td rowspan="1" class="unreservable slot"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="background: rgb(237, 237, 237); height: 0px; border: none !important;">
                            <table class="slot-table" width="100%" style="border: none; display: none;">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td id="15850908605e8209eda6554" class="reslabel" style="border:none !important;text-align:center;border-right:solid #36648B 1px !important" width="10%">
                                        07:01AM
                                    </td><td rowspan="1" class="unreservable slot"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

where I would like to find class 'unreservable slot' in class 'slots tr_mrng'.
Unfortunately, I can't find out how to handle conditions with Selenium. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution to handle tr within another table using XPATH. also , check if table is not present under iframe.

```
//tr[@class='slots tr_mrng']//table[@class='slot-table']//td[@class='unreservable slot']]
```